# Why does this Sql query shows the possible changes but does not implement it?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I want to change the prefix of my tables and the following command shows the possible changes that will take place which seems alright but does not seem to implement it.

`SELECT Concat('RENAME TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' TO fan_', SUBSTRING_INDEX(TABLE_NAME, 'pc_',-1), ';') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name like 'pc_%' and table_schema='testdbhere'`

Moreover, this isn't a writing privilege issue as changing the tables name individually works perfectly from the same user.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement it"? A query does never change data, it only selects them. If you want to change data, you need to write an update command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does the following query not win me a million dollars?

```
SELECT 'Bill Karwin bought the winning lottery ticket!' FROM DUAL;
```

Because the result of a query is just a result set. In this case, a string. The words contained in that string do not automatically come true.

You must save the result of your query to a file, and then use that file as input to the MySQL client to execute the lines as if they were an SQL script.

For what is an SQL script, but a file containing a series of strings that happen to be valid SQL statements?

Comment: I understand that Select statements just displays what an output is. I may have forgotten to mention it, but using an update statement does not work either. I'm new to mysql so I'm definitely making a mistake so could not pin point it.

Comment: Okay, if you understand that the result of a query is just a result, then what is your question? The question you posted really seems to say that you expected the strings returned by your query (whether they are RENAME TABLE or UPDATE) would be executed as SQL statements automatically.

Comment: My question was how to make the following statement also change the entire tables name in a desired database. not just show the possible outcome.

Comment: You can't make a SELECT statement execute its own results as further SQL statements. You have to capture the results and execute them yourself as a separate step. Either write code to do this, or at least a shell script. That's as far as I will help you. If you don't understand this explanation, then I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: My bad, a Shell script definitely would have made this easier. Embarrassingly something I did not think of. It would be an easy implementation. 
Thanks a lot, sometimes it never crosses your mind on implementing the obvious.